Install a package from github via Spyder within Anaconda
Good morning,
I am new to Spyder & would like to install a package there directly from github.
Note: I am using Spyder within Anaconda
The github page has a setup.py.
I saw a video where they used "pip install "git+[enter https of github]".
However, I wonder if I can run this directly in Spyder, also keeping in mind that I am within Anaconda. Or I need to add a "!" in front of pip?
Wanted to double check before doing a mistake!
Thanks a lot!
